# PHP task scheduling with Windows Task Scheduler

Tags: php, scheduled-tasks

I have a PHP script that gets information from one database table and uses it to construct another table.  It runs whenever I access it online, but the idea is to get it working with a scheduler.  I've tried using A Trigger, which wouldn't work properly, and now I'm trying Windows Task Scheduler but this doesn't seem to be doing anything either.  The .bat file I used is as follows:

```
C:\path\to\php.exe -f "path to php script"
```

I've refreshed the database table to check if any changes were made and it hasn't been updating.  I did, however, come across this question.  https://superuser.com/questions/321215/how-can-i-open-a-url-on-a-schedule-in-the-default-browser
I'm thinking this may work but since I'm running it directly on the machine that we use for this particular site, I need to know if running the command in that top answer will generate a new browser window every time the task runs.  If so, is there a way to close it after a specified period of time?  The update script takes about a minute or so to complete.

Comment: Yes, you can run PHP from the command line (I can't understand that obsession so many people have to run internal scripts through a web browser). Question is: does it work from a regular command prompt?

Comment: No.  The error indicates that it couldn't execute a require_once statement for a file in a different directory, even though the path is specified within the script itself.  At any rate, the solution in that link I provided *does* work and I didn't see any browser windows open, so I may have answered my own question.

Comment: Well, Windows is a multi-user system. When you log into your desktop with a given user, you don't see windows from other users. That doesn't mean those windows don't exist or use system resources. As I said, it's a convoluted way to accomplish an otherwise simple task.

Comment: I'm seeing that iexplore.exe*32 process are being created whenever this thing runs.  I know it's not optimal but is there a way to create a delay in the .bat file, then kill the process?

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need to even create a batch script - I'd store the whole task in Task Scheduler.

Point the program/script path to your php.exe, and in the arguments field:

```
-f C:\path\to\php\script.php
```

The path to the php script doesn't need to be in quotes. That saves the need to create a batch script and point task scheduler to that.

The script itself will not open a browser - it will silently in the background.

Comment: That one's not working.  It wouldn't run from the command prompt so I don't think this is going to work either.